# Does Phantomjs render XML+XSL?

Tags: xslt, phantomjs

I'm trying to render an XML document with an attached XSL stylesheet in phantomjs. It always shows an original XML page, without applying XSL to it. It doesn't support this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhantomJS actually does not support `XSLTProcessor`. I have tried XSLT [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxl/byHWh/) myself and got error. After searching around found [closed issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10917) on GitHub with comment

> XSLT is disabled in Qt WebKit by default. Other WebKit ports have been using the libxslt library to handle XSL transformations, but for QtWebKit such a dependency would not have been possible and the XSLT processor in WebCore had been disabled in the build system (it didn't even compile). But since Qt has developed its own xslt library and XSLT processor in the QtXmlPatterns module. This implementation is quite limited, so the things will not work properly.